# Eclipse string.xml not color coding in editor correctly

Tags: android, eclipse

This is driving me nuts.  My strings.xml file is not color coding in eclipse.  It starts out that way and other projects I have are good but not this one.  Even if I delete it and create a new one.

I have attached a screen shot.  I have also tried to reinsert every item line by line but I am  stumped.

[image]

Comment: Had this happen once. A restart of Eclipse fixed it. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work but thanks.

Comment: When you right-click on the file and expand the Open With menu, which editor is selected by default?  Are you even opening the file in the XML Editor?

Comment: oooh that worked. Nice thanks.  Make it an answer so I can except it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click the file, select "Open with" menu and make sure you're using the XML editor to view the file.

Comment: Oh sorry, answered without looking. Didn't mean to steal someone else's answer. Ran into the same problem a couple months ago.

Comment: No worries, I don't really care as long as the answer reaches the right person.

Comment: I figured as much.  I need it answered so nitind you get the up vote and I'll just answer this.  Thanks